# How can Navigating of menu item from one project to another in the same solution

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net solution there are 2 asp.net web projects. I am using asp.net menu control in one project and i need to navigate from menu item to another project web page.How is this possible ?

In project 1->Default1.aspx, menu control is there and i need to navigate url from the menu item of Project1-> Default1.aspx to Project2-> Default2.aspx